# Configure Oracle 11g Database in Oracle Linux 6

Tags: database, linux, oracle, oracle11g

For the last 2 days I've been trying to configure Oracle DB 11g in Oracle Linux 6. It has successfully installed but I can't create a database.
I have created the listener and tnsnames and tried to startup the database with the following commands:

```
    sqlplus /nolog   
    connect / as sysdba   
    startup
```

And I'm getting the following errors:

```
    ORA-00119: invalid specification for system parameter LOCAL_LISTENER
    ORA-00130: invalid listener address '(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=beta)(PORT=1521))'
```

Here my listener and tnsnames config:

listener.ora:

```
    SID_LIST_LISTENER =
     (SID_LIST =
       (SID_DESC =
         (SID_NAME = orcl)
         (ORACLE_HOME = /home/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/oracle)
       )
     )
    SUBSCRIBE_FOR_NODE_DOWN_EVENT_LISTENER=OFF

    LISTENER =
      (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
        (DESCRIPTION =
          (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
        )
      )

    ADR_BASE_ORCL = /home/oracle/app/oracle
```

tnsnames.ora:

```
    ORCL =
      (DESCRIPTION =
        (ADDRESS_LIST =
          (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
        )
        (CONNECT_DATA =
          (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
        )
      )
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Did you set your environment variables up per the [installation instructions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/install.112/e24321/pre_install.htm#i1011717)? In particular, you'll need ORACLE_SID, ORACLE_BASE, ORACLE_UNQNAME, ORACLE_HOME (remember that case is significant on Linux).  Also, if you didn't create a database as part of the installation, you'll need to run the [database creation assistant (dbca)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/create002.htm).

Comment: Here's what I have in my environment variables: export ORACLE_BASE=/home/oracle/app/oracle
export ORACLE_HOME=$ORACLE_BASE/product/11.2.0/dbhome
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib:/lib:/usr/lib
export TNS_ADMIN=$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin
export ORACLE_SID=orcl

Answer (score 0):

I only need an environment for development purposes so I've download a template VM from Oracle site's and instantiated using Virtual Box. The template is configured and it's database is running ok.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle looks for the "beta" hostname, and all your settings pinpoint to localhost. Try adding an entry in

```
/etc/hosts
```

with the following line:

```
127.0.0.1 beta
```

and try starting it up again